# How to use ajax with search bar to populate table view in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ajax, uitableview

So I'm really new to iPhone development and this is what I want to achieve. I want a search bar that uses a REST api that I've written to get back data and populate a table view.

In terms of what I've attempted - I'm not sure where to start, so I'll just post some thoughts.

What I've done is created three views - a root view, a search view and a results view. The root view should have a UISearchBarDelegate, an UITableView DataSource and an UITableViewDelegate because there needs to be a controller that can execute the search and populate the table.

However I'm not sure if this is the right approach, or even where to go next after this.

I know I should probably try more code, but I'm just really not sure where to start because this is an architecture thing - I'm not sure where the data will be passed between search and results(I think this should be in the root view) and how that root view will know when the search is done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one ViewController. Make it a delegate to the UITableView and the UISearchBar, as well as the DataSource for the tableview.  Put the searchbar in a UINavigationBar along with a button with the text "Search".  When the button is pressed take the text in the search, send it to your REST api, then set the data as the DataSource. Then just call [tableView reloadData] and the view will refresh with your updated data.